# operator does not exist: inet = text" postgresql Nhibernate

Tags: c#, npgsql

unfortunately i have to use asp.net MVC with PostgreSQL and Nhibernate  ,in the database i have a type Inet type for IP in the code its Text,i get this error when i query,event if i change the type in code to npgsqlType.Inet threw another error stating does not able to cast Inet!

```
 "42883: operator does not exist: inet = text"}
```

for this query:

```
     var stst = session.Query<Statstics>().Where(s => s.m_turbine_id== "192.168.137.2").Single();
```

Comment: Don't you have to put `inet` in front of the string in order to compare it with an `inet` field?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos which field?m_turbine_id is text

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you make and example of you mean,please?

Comment: `m_turbine_id` is a *table field*. The error complains that you tried to compare an `inet` value with a text value which suggests the field's type is `inet`. If you [check the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-net.html) you'll see that all IP literals are prefixed with `inet`, eg `inet '192.168.1.5' = inet '192.168.1.5'`. Try `.Where(s => s.m_turbine_id== "inet '192.168.137.2'")`

Comment: yes but when i change the field to npgsql.type.Inet ,again throws me another error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i changed to inet and i got MappingException: Could not determine type for: NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlInet, Npgsql, Version=3.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(m_turbine_id)

Comment: The [Supported Types and their mappings](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html) page in the docs shows that the default mapped type for `inet` is [IPAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Try `.Where(s => s.m_turbine_id== IPAddress.Parse("192.168.137.2"))` or better yet, parse the string into an IPAddress variable first `var myIP=IPAddress.Parse("192.168.137.2");` and write ``.Where(s => s.m_turbine_id== myIp)`

Comment: i changed the type to Ipaddress and have done what you said,now in the quesry i get this error:I{"42883: operator does not exist: inet = bytea"} System.Exception {Npgsql.PostgresException}

Comment: I don't know NHibernate at all, but has been written above you can't compare a PostgreSQL `inet` type to a simple string - PostgreSQL is strongly-typed that way. As Npgsql maps .NET `IPAddress` to PostgreSQL `inet`, comparing to an instance of `IPAddress` should work, so I'd focus on why NHibernate converts `IPAddress` to PostgreSQL `bytea` (which is a simple byte array).